# Interpretation of moment generating function of normal distribution.

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, moment-generating-functions

For the normal distribution, if the pdf of $X$ is $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{32 \pi}} \exp[-\frac{(x+7)^2}{32}]$, $-\infty<x<\infty$, then $X$ is $N(-7,16)$
with a mean $\mu=-7$, a variance $\sigma^2=16$, and the moment generating function $M(t)=\exp(-7t+8t^2)$.

> Question 1: I don't see why has normal distribution of $N(-7,16)$, and how to explain the moment generating function $M(t)=\exp(-7t+8t^2)$?

Comment: Compare $f$ and the pdf of $N(-7,16)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then it has pdf
$$
f_{\mu,\sigma^2}(x) = \tfrac1{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \exp\bigl( - \tfrac1{2\sigma^2} ( x - \mu )^2 \bigr)
\quad\text{for}\quad
x \in \mathbb R.
$$
This is just the definition of a normal distribution.
Setting $\mu := -7$ and $\sigma^2 := 16$, one recovers the special case.

Now, to find the moment generating function, we need to calculate
$$ \textstyle
M(t)
=
\mathbb E(e^{tX})
=
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx} f_{\mu,\sigma^2}(x) dx
=
\tfrac1{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx} \exp\bigl( - \tfrac1{2\sigma^2} ( x - \mu )^2 \bigr) dx.
$$
Can you try to solve this?

Hint: let $y := (x - \mu)/\sigma$; this is a "renormalised" version.
Note that $(X - \mu)/\sigma \sim N(0,1)$. With this change of variables, you need only calculate it for $N(0,1)$, ie $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma^2 = 1$.
To solve the integral, combine the two $e^{...}$ terms and complete the square.